# Programmatically generating temporary AWS API Keys using JS SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm using [AWS Javascript SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#createApiKey-property) to create API Keys. I now wanna create API Keys for some short period of time say for 15 days and need to remove/disable the keys after that time.

Is there any best way to do it programmatically preferably using anything like functions of their JavaScript SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no current way to automatically expire API keys after a set amount of time, however it should be pretty trivial to implement yourself.

For example, you could write a scheduled Lambda function that scans through the API Keys and disables them based on their createdDate or contents of description field.

Comment: Though I didn't get any other answer to my question and based on your response, I can't do that the way I want, so I'm marking your answer as accepted answer.